# End of Statement Expected, beginner

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Please help me solve. I'm still beginner

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class MBranches
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
        If Page.IsValid Then
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|APU.mdf;Integrated Security=true; User Instance=true"
            conn.Open()
                Dim SqlString As String = "INSERT INTO tblBranch (BranchName, BranchAddress, BranchContactNumber) VALUES ("& txtName.Text &","& txtAddress.Text &","& txtCNumber.Text")"
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple syntax error, which Visual Studio should be indicating clearly. You are missing an ampersand & in your SqlString.

You should find this for yourself.. but it's at the end of the line.

Comment: Now got another error. It stated "'txtAddress' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Comment: So do you have something named `txtAddress`? Presumably this should be the name of a textbox on a form.

Comment: yes. I have it. What I'm trying to do now is submit data in textbox into database.

Comment: Double-check the name of the textbox.. again. txtName is available, so compare this, and its properties, to those of txtAddress to see why one is available and the other isn't.

Comment: Others also have this error........... ><

Comment: Can I email my file to you and let you check? Because it's really urgent. It really appreciate if you able to make it.